# Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0

Tags: ffmpeg, clipbucket

I can't play a video using clipbucket after installation, getting conversion status as completed but while playing the video I get an message as "not available"

**Conversion file**

```
Checking File ....
File : /var/www/html/files/conversion_queue/14958856828d300.mp4
File Exists : Yes

Preparing file...
format : mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2

duration : 62.09

size : 4480694

bitrate : 577316

video_width : 640

video_height : 360

video_wh_ratio : 1.7777777777778

video_codec : h264

video_rate : 23.976023976024

video_bitrate : 479302

video_color : N/A

audio_codec : aac

audio_bitrate : 95999

audio_rate : 44100

audio_channels : 2

path : /var/www/html/files/conversion_queue/14958856828d300.mp4

rotation : 0

======Converting Video=========

Starting : Thumbs Generation


=======Low Resolution Conversion=======


Sarting : Generating Low resolution video @ 2017-05-27 17:18:11

Converting Video SD File

Command : /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/files/conversion_queue/14958856828d300.mp4 -vcodec flv -acodec libmp3lame -s 640x360 -preset medium -f mp4 -b:v 512000 -minrate 512000 -maxrate 512000 -b:a 128000 -minrate 128000 -maxrate 128000 -r 25 -ar 22050 /var/www/html/files/videos/2017/05/27/14958856828d300-sd.mp4

ffmpeg output : ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
libavutil 54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
libavcodec 56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
libavformat 56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
libavdevice 56. 4.100 / 56. 4.100
libavfilter 5. 11.102 / 5. 11.102
libavresample 2. 1. 0 / 2. 1. 0
libswscale 3. 1.101 / 3. 1.101
libswresample 1. 1.100 / 1. 1.100
libpostproc 53. 3.100 / 53. 3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/files/conversion_queue/14958856828d300.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand : mp42
minor_version : 0
compatible_brands: isommp42
creation_time : 2016-03-17 10:27:42
Duration: 00:01:02.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 577 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 479 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2016-03-17 10:27:42
handler_name : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Codec AVOption preset (Set the encoding preset (cf. x264 --fullhelp)) specified for output file #0 (/var/www/html/files/videos/2017/05/27/14958856828d300-sd.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
[flv @ 0x2506080] Either both buffer size and max rate or neither must be specified
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/html/files/videos/2017/05/27/14958856828d300-sd.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand : mp42
minor_version : 0
compatible_brands: isommp42
Stream #0:0(und): Video: flv1, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0, 25 fps (default)
Metadata:
handler_name : VideoHandler
encoder : Lavc56.26.100 flv
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp3, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2016-03-17 10:27:42
handler_name : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
encoder : Lavc56.26.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> flv1 (flv))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height


Sarting : MP4Box Conversion for SD

MP4Box Command : /usr/local/bin/MP4Box -inter 0.5 /var/www/html/files/videos/2017/05/27/14958856828d300-sd.mp4 -tmp /var/www/html/files/temp

output : Error opening file /var/www/html/files/videos/2017/05/27/14958856828d300-sd.mp4: IsoMedia File is truncated


Conversion Status : Successful @ 2017-05-27 17:18:11


output_format : mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2

output_duration : 62.09

output_size : 4480694

output_bitrate : 577316

output_video_width : 640

output_video_height : 360

output_video_wh_ratio : 1.7777777777778

output_video_codec : h264

output_video_rate : 23.976023976024

output_video_bitrate : 479302

output_video_color : N/A

output_audio_codec : aac

output_audio_bitrate : 95999

output_audio_rate : 44100

output_audio_channels : 2

output_path : /var/www/html/files/conversion_queue/14958856828d300.mp4

output_rotation : 0


Time Took : 9.2965 seconds

conversion_status : completed 


**Error Messages**

Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

output : Error opening file /var/www/html/files/videos/2017/05/27/14958856828d300-sd.mp4: IsoMedia File is truncated
```

Comment: FFmpeg does not write FLV1 streams (as created due to `-c:v flv`) into MP4. Either switch output format to `.flv` or use `-c:v libx264`.

Comment: I tried .flv format but still not working

Comment: In your attempt, did you remove `-f mp4`? You have to.

Comment: actually I tried uploading a .flv video instead of .mp4 also I am new to ffmpeg, so not sure on how to use -c:v libx264 and all can you please help me out

Comment: FLV command: `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/files/conversion_queue/14958856828d300.mp4 -vcodec flv -acodec libmp3lame -s 640x360 -b:v 512k -minrate 512k -maxrate 512k -b:a 128k -r 25 -ar 22050 /var/www/html/files/videos/2017/05/27/14958856828d300-sd.flv`

Comment: MP4 command: `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/files/conversion_queue/14958856828d300.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -s 640x360 -preset medium -b:v 512k -minrate 512k -maxrate 512k -b:a 128k -r 25 -ar 22050 /var/www/html/files/videos/2017/05/27/14958856828d300-sd.mp4`

Comment: Thankyou,it did help me convert the video but still getting the same errors when I try to open it with clipbucket